# DotNetNuke Blog urls and links

Tags: module, blogs, dotnetnuke

I'm not sure why, but we have a dedicated Blog page on our site with some latest entires showing on the home page. Suddenly all links like the title of the entry and the Read More link are pointing to the home page to show the blog entry instead of the blog page.

I've tried regenerating the permalinks but that didn't help. I also can't find a setting somewhere that allows me to point the home page blog summaries to open on the actual blog page.

Anyone know what's going on?

Thanks,
Jacques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this happens with the DNN Blog Module when you have its components spread across different pages and you then edit the blog entry on a different page from the normal page. The only way I saw to fix this is to go back to the original blog page, go to the blog entry, hit edit and then save.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar trouble in that my localhost DNN site would redirect to our live/production website on the publicly accessible url.  I think the reason for the problem is the same - I think its a bug with the DNN blog module's 'SEO Friendly URL' setting.

If the permalinks (in the permalink field of the dnn_BLOG_Entries) use the seo friendly format (for ex: http://somesite.com/Blog/tabid/xx/Entryid/xx/your-blog-tile.aspx) due to the blog 'seo friendly format' setting then clicking the blog entry link from the blog page tends to mis-direct - in my case to the production website instead of the localhost website.

Un-checking the blog 'seo friendly' setting and re-building the permalinks (which doesn't seem to affect anything?) - and clicking 'update' in the blog settings page to commit the change - *AND THEN* editing each blog entry - ie go into edit mode to edit it and just re-saving - seems to resolve the problem, as this causes the permalink field in the dnn_Blog_Entries table to be updated correctly.  However, you are stuck with non seo-friendly url permalinks (for ex:http://somesite.com/Blog/tabid/xx/Entryid/xx/Default.aspx).

This is as of latest DNN 7.x as of Feb 2013.